# Add/remove repeated section items by Javascript

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to add/delete repeated grid items by Javascript because of repeat control DOM has to be customized and placed in other place.

Is there any way to do this inserting or deleting by javascipt?

I have tryied this without success:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.dispatchEvent(
    {
        targetId:  'my-enclosin-reapeated-section',
        eventName: 'xforms-insert'
    }
);
```

Here is the entire form source code: https://pastebin.com/P3VK4hKm

In this case I am trying:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.dispatchEvent(
    {
        targetId:  'section-3-iteration',
        eventName: 'xforms-insert'
    }
);
```

Orbeon version is 2018.2.3 PE

Comment: You need to provide more info and a minimum reproducible example in order to get help with your problem

Comment: Robert I have attached entire Orbeon Source Code

Comment: Keep in mind that if there is no documented public API for this, whatever you do is likely to break at the next Orbeon Forms release. This said the closest you could do is to simulate a click on an existing "add" or "remove" button.